# Using VB.NET to create command line parsing and Dictionary Object

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, command-line, command

This is a 2 part question. Feel free to answer part 1 or part 2 or both.

Part 1:

I need to create some command line code that will allow me to take a file in a folder and parse the text in an xml file. I wrote a bit of code but it does not seem to be working for some reason:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    'Create an XML reader.
    Using reader As xmlreader = xmlreader.create("c:\success.xml")
        While reader.read()
            'check for start elements.
            If reader.isstartelement() Then

                'see if which element
                If reader.name = "success" Then
                    console.writeline("start <parsing> element.")
                    Dim attribute As String = reader("name")
                    If attribute IsNot Nothing Then
                        console.writeline(" Has attribure name: {0}", attribute)
                    End If

                    'text date.
                    If reader.read() Then
                        console.writeline(" Text node: {0}", reader.value.trim())
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        End While
    End Using

End Sub
```

Part 2:

I also need to create a Dictionary Object so I can store keys and variables. I need to have some more advice on developing this dictionary object and calling it later. The code is:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dictionary As New dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim variable As String = "FirstName"
    Dim variablevalue As String = "David"

    dictionary.add(variable, variablevalue)

    variablevalue = dictionary(variable)

End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: where does the commandline come into play?

Comment: The application itself is written to run in the background. Command prompt runs when i run debug on this program. The program itself is written in vb. I will be honest I am new to this and am learning as I go. Please ask me as many questions as possible and I will do my best to respond in a complete manner.

Comment: @user3241357 - Sample source data, sample processed data and and errors or wrong processed data would help as well.  When you say command line, do you mean you want to send arguments to the app, or do you just mean that it is a console app that doesn't run with a GUI?

Comment: Correct. I want it to run in the background after a trigger from winautomation is set off. I do not want a GUI. What I need to happen is this. Win automation is running and monitoring a folder for .xml files. Once an .xml file hits that folder it runs this program. This program needs to first parse the xml file and store specific variables in a dictionary object. Currently the program calls a specifically named file which needs to be changed to a folder rather than a file and loop until there are no more files in the folder. Please let me know if there are any other questions that I can answer